# How to verify if 3 different string List´s in c# console app have the excactly same size of entries

Tags: c#, if-statement

Hello i have this code here.

```
List<string> list = BarCode.Split(';').ToList();
List<string> list2 = OBS.Split(';').ToList();
List<string> list3 = OBS2.Split(';').ToList();
```

I want to verify in a if statment if they have the same size of entries.

How can i do that?

Comment: What have you tried, this can go a few ways...

Comment: Hello @zaggler i have figured it out, thank you either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing

```
int sizeList1 = list.Count;
int sizeList2 = list2.Count;
int sizeList3 = list3.Count;
if (sizeList1 == sizeList2 && sizeList1 == sizeList3)
{

}
```

Comment: No i legit asked because i didn´t know, but i tried this out and it worked for me and for what i want to acomplish, if other readers can benefit from it why not Mr.@TimSchmelter

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ you can use `All`, it's readable even with many lists:

```
bool sameSize = new[]{list2, list3}.All(l => l.Count == list.Count);
```

With an `if`:

```
if(list.Count == list2.Count && list.Count == list3.Count)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just compare its counts.

```
bool isSameSize = list.Count == list2.Count && list2.Count == list3.Count;
```